# jaxb/ how to take text in element

Tags: html, jaxb

I have the next element:

```
<div id="one"> Hello! </div>
```

I want to take, by jaxb, the "Hello!" string. How can I do this?

---

**UPDATE**

I have a class, with `@XmlElement`. for example, the class 'div', and one of it members is the List span. So:

```
public class div {

    private List<Span> span;
    private List<Span> ls;

    public List<Span> getSpan() {
        return span;
    }

    public void setSpan(List<Span> span) {
        for (int i = 0 ; i<span.size(); i++){ 
            ls.add(span.get(i));
        } 
        this.span = span; 
    }

}
```

and I want it value also. So I write: public String getValue() { return value; }

```
'@XmlValue' 
public void setValue(String value) { this.value = value; }
```

Comment: Some context would be useful...

Answer (score 1):

You could leverage the `@XmlValue` annotation to do the following:

```java
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Div {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String id;

    @XmlValue
    private String value;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-complex-types-with-simple.html

Comment: I did it, but it gives me the next error: If a class has '@XmlElement' property, it cannot have '@XmlValue' property. I try use xmlMixed, but this doesn't help. Do you know where I need to put the '@XMLmixed'? I put it with the '@xmlValue' annotaion

Comment: @AdamSh - What does the class you are trying to map this to look like?

Comment: I have a class, with '@XmlElement'. for example, the class 'div', and one of it members is the List<Span> span. So:  'public List<Span> getSpan() {
  return span;
 }

 @XmlElement
 public void setSpan(List<Span> span) {
  for (int i = 0 ; i<span.size(); i++){
   ls.add(span.get(i));}
  this.span = span;
 }'
and I want it value also. So I write: public String getValue() {
  return value;
 }

 '@XmlValue'
 public void setValue(String value) {
  this.value = value;
 }